# How to fetch response from a callback URL using php?

Tags: php, api, curl, gupshup, callbackurl

I want to build a WhatsApp bot, for that, we are using Gupshup WhatsApp bot API, for integration they asked to give a callback URL, so created index.php in cPanel of one domain(https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/index.php), and gave the URL (https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/). As per their [API documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5tKl.png), they will pass a response to that URL, so I want to fetch that. Here is the remaining part of API documentation [API documentation2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC7DM.png), [API documentation3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKqNv.png), [API documentation4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moXhi.png). So I created one curl.php named file, that code is given below.

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/');
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  if (curl_errno($ch)) 
   {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch) ."\n";
   }
  else
   {
      $result_value = json_decode($result,true,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      echo $result_value;
      // var_dump($result_value);   
   }
 curl_close($ch);
?>
```

they provided a collection of API for reference, but I am getting the wrong result. In their collection API have the result,
[Collection API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YIPC.png)

but I am getting this,
[myresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nfpJ.png)

What is the wrong in this code? Can anyone please help me...

Comment: Why are you trying to make a request to `https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/` here? That is not how a callback URL works - _their_ servers will make a request to that URL. What you need to do, inside that script, is take the received POST data, and do something with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Callback URL should contain a program that receive a POST data as JSON, Go ahead to decode the JSON data, using the data received, proceed with what ever logic you plan to execute.

```
//this should be in your call back URL index.php

$post_data_expected = file_get_contents("php://input");

$decoded_data = json_decode($post_data_expected, true);
```

You can your POSTMAN to always test your callback URL to see it behaves the way you expects.

Comment: Added this code in index.php.                                                                                         `<?php

$post_data_expected = file_get_contents("https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/");

$decoded_data = json_decode($post_data_expected, true);
echo $decoded_data;
?>` and tested in postman but nothing displayed. I just put this  URL "https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/" and POST request. Is there anything additional I want to add in postman header or in code?? @Apollos Geofrey

Comment: take note: this line shouldn't be, 
$post_data_expected = file_get_contents("https://sample_url/WhatsappBot/");
instead :
$post_data_expected = file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: did you install postman on your machine or trying this online?

Comment: edited the code like you said, `<?php

$post_data_expected = file_get_contents("php://input");

$decoded_data = json_decode($post_data_expected, true);
echo $decoded_data;
?>`. now also no result. I tested in postman, which I already installed in my computer.

Comment: well, i don't know how u are doing this. but instead of using 
<?php echo $decoded_data; ?>
 use 
<?php print_r($decoded_data); ?>
 or 
<?php var_dump($decoded_data); ?>

Comment: while using postman, make sure you are using the POST method, data should be posted as JSON as well as a valid URL (could be that of your local-host server as well eg. {http://localhost/index.php}). it should provide a feedback response which should be either an error or expected result.